# Regex: How to repeat group area?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

How can I repeat a certain part of a match area without writing it multiple times?

For example:

```
txt = '1. Reserve December 31, prior year.................................................................................................................. ..4,587,658,997 .......................... .1,030,275,014 .....136,963,988 .......................... .3,276,184,545 .....144,235,450 .......................... .......................... .......................... .......................... ..........................'

splitter = '^([\d.]+)(.*?)\.\s\.[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?'

parts = re.match(splitter, x, re.DOTALL)
```

The first part of my regex expression, `^([\d.]+)(.*?)\.\s\.` grabs the row number, and title:

> 1. Reserve December 31, prior year

after that I have to repeat this section 12 times to ensure I get 12 additional matches for the numbers after the title `[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?`.

If there aren't 12 numbers it returns `None` for that specific match.

Is there a way I can repeat this expression 12 times without having to write such a long regex expression? I tried  `(?:[\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?){12}` but no dice.

Comment: I think this is possible if you use the `regex` instead of the `re` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to put your second part into a group by putting () around it and then putting your exact count outside of the group like this:

```
checkIt = re.compile(r'^([\d.]+)(.*?)\.\s\.([\.\s]+(\(*\d[\d,.]*\)*)?){12}')
if checkIt.match(text):
    do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the separate values using the regex [PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and loop the captures collection to get the separate numbers.

You could add an anchor `$` to the end of the string, and repeat matching the numbers 12 times.

If there are no 12 numbers, the match will be None.

Instead of using `(.*?)` you could make the pattern a bit more specific and reduce the backtracking in case there is no match.

```
^(\d+\.)\s(\w+(?:\s+[\w,]+)*)(?:[.\s]+\.(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)){12}+[.\s]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/69QIjS/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##7VS9asMwEN71FIfpIMWHsCz/BkqXPkHXKAXXVRIPso2kNA2lz@7KSaBLyJgp36T7fk5wcDce/W7o5TR1ZhysB6u3@puQsfFe2x6ewUbvVH3GijPlqDrE9GWpXLxSB1zHbMFCueLKrYNhtp1KXIdX0NiPSH/jk7x4iogL3SLB4U07bb80vOpWmw9tQQqE0XaDhaNuLL87gPMM86rEIq@wrku4ZRWYyATTMsdEZGenkAXWhcS6qm5GZYgVKKrwWZZfolmGqcwxy5Ob0ftJj/E/xn/CFTIiZr4I84ngpvHtjl7uBIJjhHQbMEsCAWGbe08N39phP1LB2BU2vbCbsPctdD0Y3jaj31vtqGTnPv@plpFp@gM)

For example

```
import regex

pattern = r"^(\d+\.)\s(\w+(?:\s+[\w,]+)*)(?:[.\s]+\.(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)){12}+[.\s]*$"
s = "1. Reserve December 31, prior year.................................................................................................................. ..4,587,658,997 .......................... .1,030,275,014 .....136,963,988 .......................... .3,276,184,545 .....144,235,450 .......................... .......................... .......................... .......................... ............................................................................................................................................ ..4,587,658,997 .......................... .1,030,275,014 .....136,963,988 .......................... .3,276,184,545 .....144,235,450 .......................... .......................... .......................... .......................... ............................................................................................................................................ ..4,587,658,997 .......4,587,658,997 ....."
m = regex.match(pattern, s)

if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
    for c in m.captures(3):
        print(c)
```

Output

```
1.
Reserve December 31, prior year
4,587,658,997
1,030,275,014
136,963,988
3,276,184,545
144,235,450
4,587,658,997
1,030,275,014
136,963,988
3,276,184,545
144,235,450
4,587,658,997
4,587,658,997
```